# How to adjust specific error in pivot_longer() in R

Tags: r, tidyr

Could you help me adjust my `Sumpk` variable? Unfortunately it gives an error when I run.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- structure(
  list(date1 = c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-04-02","2021-04-02","2021-04-08","2021-04-08"),
       Code = c("ABC","CDE","ABC","CDE"),
       Week= c("Friday","Friday","Thursday","Thursday"),
       DR1 = c(11,17,14,13),
       DR01 = c(14,11,14,13), DR02= c(14,12,16,17),DR03= c(19,15,14,13),
       DR04 = c(15,14,13,13)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
> df1
       date1      date2 Code     Week DR1 DR01 DR02 DR03 DR04
1 2021-06-28 2021-04-02  ABC   Friday  11   14   14   19   15
2 2021-06-28 2021-04-02  CDE   Friday  17   11   12   15   14
3 2021-06-28 2021-04-08  ABC Thursday  14   14   16   14   13
4 2021-06-28 2021-04-08  CDE Thursday  13   13   17   13   13
x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR"))

x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
pk<-select(x, date2,Code, Week, DR1, ends_with("PV"))

med<-pk %>%
  group_by(Code, Week) %>%
  summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))
> med
# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Groups:   Code [2]
  Code  Week     DR1_PV DR01_PV DR02_PV DR03_PV DR04_PV
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 ABC   Friday        0      -3      -3      -8      -4
2 ABC   Thursday      0       0      -2       0       1
3 CDE   Friday        0       6       5       2       3
4 CDE   Thursday      0       0      -4       0       0

Sumpk<-df1%>%
  pivot_longer(-c(date1:Week)) %>%
  left_join(med %>% rename_with( ~str_remove(., "_PV")) %>% 
              pivot_longer(-Week, values_to = "med")) %>%
  mutate(new_value = value + med) %>%
  select(-c(value:med)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = new_value, 
              names_glue = '{name}_{name}_PV')
```

Output of `Sumpk`
[image]

Comment: What is your input `df1` or `med` ? and the screenshot attached is the expected output ? How do you calculate it ?

Comment: Ronak, the output is basically the sum of columns `DR01 to DR04` of `df1` with the results obtained by the variable `med`. Example: The value of `DR01` of the 02/04 which is a Friday for the ABC category is 14. Therefore, I need to add this value with the result obtained by the variable `med `for the ABC category of the Friday which in this case - 3. Therefore: 14 + (-3) = 11. Did you understand better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this `inner_join` method -

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  inner_join(med, by = c('Code', 'Week')) %>%
  mutate(across(DR1:DR04, ~.x + get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')), 
         .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
  select(date1:Week, DR1_DR1_PV:DR04_DR04_PV)

#       date1      date2 Code     Week DR1_DR1_PV DR01_DR01_PV DR02_DR02_PV DR03_DR03_PV DR04_DR04_PV
#1 2021-06-28 2021-04-02  ABC   Friday         11           11           11           11           11
#2 2021-06-28 2021-04-02  CDE   Friday         17           17           17           17           17
#3 2021-06-28 2021-04-08  ABC Thursday         14           14           14           14           14
#4 2021-06-28 2021-04-08  CDE Thursday         13           13           13           13           13
```

Another method which would work for dynamic columns would be -

```
df3 <- df1 %>%  inner_join(med, by = c('Code', 'Week'))
cols <- grep('DR', names(df1), value = TRUE)
new_cols <- paste(cols, cols, 'PV', sep = '_')
df3[new_cols] <- df1[cols] + df3[paste0(cols, '_PV')]
df3 %>% select(date1:Week, all_of(new_cols))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I just need the name DR01_DR01_PV for me to remember that a sum was made.

Comment: How about the updated answer?

Comment: Ronak, that's right. Thanks for that. But, I have a question: in the code you specify up to `DR04`. And then to select make `DR04_DR04_PV`. So I will always need to specify the last column number?.Is there any way you don't need to specify?

Comment: You can drop entire `select` statement altogether if you want to keep all the columns. Alternatively, you can use `last_col()` function to select till last column without specifying the name i.e `select(date1:Week, DR1_DR1_PV:last_col())`

Comment: Thanks Ronak, I can't do: `mutate(across(DR1:last_col(), ~.x + get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV'))` ?

Comment: No because after `inner_join` `last_col()` is `DR04_PV` and not `DR04`.

Comment: @JVieira I have updated the answer which should work completely dynamically for all the columns. You don't need to specify any column names. Maybe that is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In `left_join` part, because `Code` variable is character, it occurs an error. If you remove this, error will be removed but depends on your purpose, it may need to handle another way.

```
Sumpk<- df1%>%
  pivot_longer(-c(date1:Week)) %>%
  left_join(med %>% ungroup %>% select(-Code) %>% rename_with( ~str_remove(., "_PV")) %>% 
              pivot_longer(-Week, values_to = "med")) %>%
  mutate(new_value = value + med) %>%
  select(-c(value:med)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = new_value, 
              names_glue = '{name}_{name}_PV')

head(Sumpk)
# A tibble: 6 x 12
  date1      date2 Code  Week  DR1_DR1_PV DR01_DR01_PV DR02_DR02_PV DR03_DR03_PV
  <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr> <list>     <list>       <list>       <list>      
1 2021-06-28 2021~ ABC   Frid~ <dbl [3]>  <dbl [3]>    <dbl [3]>    <dbl [3]>   
2 2021-06-28 2021~ CDE   Satu~ <dbl [3]>  <dbl [3]>    <dbl [3]>    <dbl [3]>   
3 2021-06-28 2021~ EFG   Thur~ <dbl [2]>  <dbl [2]>    <dbl [2]>    <dbl [2]>   
4 2021-06-28 2021~ HIJ   Frid~ <dbl [3]>  <dbl [3]>    <dbl [3]>    <dbl [3]>   
5 2021-06-28 2021~ ABC   Satu~ <dbl [3]>  <dbl [3]>    <dbl [3]>    <dbl [3]>   
6 2021-06-28 2021~ CDE   Thur~ <dbl [2]>  <dbl [2]>    <dbl [2]>    <dbl [2]>   
# ... with 4 more variables: DR04_DR04_PV <list>, DR05_DR05_PV <list>,
#   DR06_DR06_PV <list>, DR07_DR07_PV <list>
```

Comment: Sorry Park, I didn't explain the issue very well. I tweaked the `df1` database for better understanding and also inserted the output table in the question. Note that in `DR01_DR01_PV` it is the sum of  `DR01` of  `df1` database with `DRO1_PV` of variable `med`.